# Mismatch of date while using date format for specific date in swift 3

Tags: date, swift3, ios10, nsdateformatter, milliseconds

If the date is Mar 31, 2017 11:59:59 PM , If I use

```
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter =
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d,yyyy HH:mm:ss a"
        return formatter
    }()
```

above format and after converting seconds, that seconds represent the date Mar 31, 2017 12:59:59 PM

```
cellbidEndseconds  = (Int)((dateFormatter.date(from:arrMap_biddingDateEnd[indexPath.row])?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)
```

Where was the error, Can someone figure it out and update?

Comment: 12-hour format is `hh`

Comment: You ignore locale and local time zone which should be set both.

Comment: @Sulthan No change in result even after setting locale and local time zone also

Comment: @vadian If I use hh,,, EXC_breakpoint crash at the line where I was converting date to milliseconds

Comment: Then adjust the code to convert milliseconds. Anyway `hh` resolves the wrong hour.

Comment: Nothing wrong in conversion of milliseonds

Comment: You need to show more code than this. What's the actual line that caused error?

Comment: @CodeDifferent You can see the other line of code which converts date formatted string to milliseconds, For the above given date(Mar 31, 2017 11:59:59 PM) if you calculate milliseconds and if you check on epoch time it is giving Mar 31, 2017 12:59:59 PM which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you convert a `Double` to `Int`. Further, `timeIntervalSince1970` returns the number of *seconds* since midnight Jan 1, 1970. You need to multiply it by 1000 to get miliseconds:

```
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: arrMap_biddingDateEnd[indexPath.row]) {
    cellbidEndMillis = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
} else {
    print("Cannot convert date")
}
```

**Also:** if you call `print(date)`, it always prints the date in GMT, which may appear to be a few hours off compared to your local time. You need to mentally convert it to your local timezone (or write a method to do that for you). This is the a big source of confusion I see on StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually that was seconds only, variable name i updated. Converting to seconds through 'if let' is best way I agree. But ,if i am not sure that i will be getting date then I have to use. But I am pretty sure I will be getting date from array. Then it does not make any difference. I have tried by checking with local time zone and locale also. No difference in result.